# Software for recognizing sorting/renaming .mp3

Tags: windows, mp3

I know that there are lots of programs that can rename and sort mp3 after ID3 tag.

BUT, is there a program that can recognize them if the mp3 has no ID3 tag and is named "track1.mp3"?

I am looking for something that works similar to SoundHound or Shazam (analyze mp3 after the song) for Windows, that can rename and tag all my songs. Or at least most of them.

I need a free program to do this.

EDIT:

After trying **lots** of software, the only one I found that could identify (even some foreign language) songs was [MusicBee](http://getmusicbee.com/)

Comment: I don't know such software (especially not for Windows), but a keyword and clue to its possibility are CD rippers doing so for the tracks using sources like CDDB. Maybe this rings a bell for someone, who then can post an answer ;) And while waiting for that, have a look at [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mp3+identify+song&ie=UTF-8): it could very well be that in an hour or so you come up with your own answer ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [beets](http://beets.radbox.org) to organize my music library. It is completely free and open source, and should work on Windows as long as you have python installed.

See the [Getting started guide](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/main.html) for Windows install instructions.

It can grab the metadata from the [Musicbrainz](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/main.html#installing-on-windows) database, and can identify the song by its "acoustic fingerprint", similar to how SoundHound or Shazam does it, or using the filename or existing partial metadata.

It also has a web interface that you can use to browse your music library and play songs on any html5 capable browser.

It also supports plugins, so almost anything is possible, such as transcoding files into different formats, checking your library for duplicate tracks, and creating Spotify playlists. See [here](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/main.html#configuring) for more.

## Importing Instructions

1. First [install beets](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/main.html#installing-on-windows) as mentioned above.
2. Next [edit your configuration file](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/main.html#configuring). Tell it the directory of your existing music, and the library file location e.g.

   ```
   directory: ~/music  
   library: ~/data/musiclibrary.blb
   ```

   There are more details on the [website](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/main.html#configuring)
3. Next install the dependencies for the Acoustid plugin (it finds the acoustic fingerprint)

   ```
   $ pip install pyacoustid
   ```

   Download [Chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint). Remember to add the fpcalc binary to your PATH environment variable. ([See here](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/chroma.html#installing-the-binary-command-line-tool))
4. Enable the `chroma` plugin in your config file 
   (see [here](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/index.html#using-plugins))
5. Optionally, help the Acoustid database by [submitting](http://beets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/chroma.html#submitting-fingerprints) your music fingerprints
6. Next import the files using `beet import MUSICDIR` on the commandline and follow the prompts.
   Note this is a very long and interactive process, so make sure you have some time set aside. Beets and the chromaprint plugin should edit the metadata on the files.

Comment: This is a bit overkill for me, but I like the idea. So if You update your answer with a step by step guide(you don't have to go deep into details), from importing the music into beets - to making the .mp3 files identified and corrected data; and it will work for me as well, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MusicBee](http://getmusicbee.com/).

Simply select all the files in the library->Right click menu->Auto-tag by track->Identify track and update tags.

Now you can choose to update files based on digital sound signature or not, update blank field only or all etc

---

Also, from http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-mp3-tag-editor.htm :

> Mp3tagMp3tag is a good choice if you prefer to have a user interface
>   with a normal windows menu. Mp3tag has the advantage of a simple and
>   clean design with a powerful and yet easy-to-use tool to edit tags of
>   MP3 files.
>
> Basic tags are shown in a customizable front panel. Extended tags are
>   shown in a separate window for all existing tags stored in your MP3
>   files. If a tag for lyrics or other info does not exist, it can be
>   added, or if a tag is repeated, it can be removed easily.
>
> Mp3tag allows you to rename files based on the tag information, import
>   or export tag information and create playlists. `It supports online
>   Amazon, freedb, MusicBrainz and other database look-ups, allowing you
>   to auto tag and embed multiple images for album covers`.
>
> It also has a powerful Web Sources Framework, allowing you to get
>   album info from additional online databases. The latest web sources
>   are available from Mp3tag Forums at Web Sources Archive. You can
>   download the ones you need, and extract them to your Mp3tag data
>   folder in order to gain access to more online databases for auto
>   tagging.

I used this one a year or two ago, to do what you are trying to do and it worked.

> MusicBrainz [PicardMusicBrainz](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-mp3-tag-editor.htm#MusicBrainz-Picard) Picard runs on multi platforms and
>   adopts a new tagging concept that is album oriented, as opposed to
>   tracks or files oriented tagging.
>
> `It identifies track information by comparing a unique digital
>   thumbprint to the information in the MusicBrainz database`. Once the
>   tracks are best matched, you can save their respective tag information
>   into selected MP3 files. How To Tag Files With Picard is a helpful
>   guide for a quick start.
>
> As with Mp3tag, checking the details of a selected file evokes a list
>   of all existing tags, including lyrics, which you can then edit. If a
>   tag doesn't currently exist, you can always add it.
>
> But in the version under review, cover art edits aren't possible
>   except by updating from online databases.

Comment: So I have downloaded a well known song from songily.com for testing, those songs have 0 information in them. MusicBee had no idea, gave me like 126 results for a well known Linkin Park song including some christmas songs. I have already been on the site you gave me before, and I found nothing. PicardMusicBrainz can only guess the information from tags/file name, but not identify them from 0.

Comment: Yet, MusicBee is the best free auto tagging program that I tried. If I will not get any better software names, than I will accept your answer as best solution.

Answer (score 0):

[SongKong](http://www.jthink.net/songkong) is designed to identify and rename music files, and it can recognize them if the audio has no ID3 tag and is named "track1.mp3" using *Acoustic Fingerprinting*

It can be used on a collection of any size, and runs without requiring any other software on OSX and Windows.

It is not free, but you can use the free trial to generate a html report showing exactly what every song has been matched, you could then use this to manually edit your tags or buy the software and have it do it for you.

This [video](https://youtu.be/JzTQPaGPDrs?list=PLBEfu8eXW2xq54kLV_Gw5ZnG6igZEM6KO) shows the matching process in action

Disclaimer:**I am the SongKong developer**.

Comment: Sounds nice. Will try it asap. Since You are the developer, I assume that I can ask some technical questions. What engine does it use? Can it recognize songs from other languages or only 'well known' (pop) music?

Comment: @Divin3 it uses http://acoustid.org for fingerprinting allowing matches to http://musicbrainz.org - it is language and genre agnostic, it can also do metadata matches to musicbrainz and http://www.discogs.com. MusicBrainz has songs from many languages and countries including a huge amount of Japanese releases, hope that helps.